# apt-get doesn't find phpldapadmin in Debian 9 (Stretch)

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, ldap

I am trying to install the `phpldapadmin` package in order to test the LDAP server that I have installed, but when I try to run `apt-get install phpldapadmin` it says that the `phpldapadmin` package is not found. Do I need to add any extra repository?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`phpldapadmin`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/phpldapadmin) was removed from Debian Stretch in May because it was [blocking the PHP 7 transition](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=821585); that was fixed in August, but before it had time to migrate to Stretch, another [serious bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=834015) was discovered. As a result, it is being kept out of Stretch.

It *is* nevertheless possible to install `phpldapadmin`. I tried installing it locally and I didn't encounter the bug indicated above; it appears to work with its dependencies from Stretch. The safest solution is to [download it manually](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/phpldapadmin/download), and install it with `dpkg -i`, followed by `apt-get -f install` to install the missing dependencies (or install it using [`gdebi`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gdebi) which will take care of all that for you).

Alternatively, you could add Debian Sid to your repositories, with a low pin-priority; but I'll let you investigate that yourself if you feel it's appropriate. (Start with the [Debian Testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) wiki page, and the [best practices for testing/sid users](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable#What_are_some_best_practices_for_testing.2Fsid_users.3F).)

Comment: ran on Debian 9 without problem, just had to setup the /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php to fit my login and dc,dc